# API Gateway calling index page from S3 but unable to load js file

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway

I am testing a solution to use Cognito to authorise using Azure AD and then landing at API gateway URL. This API Gateway will load an S3 bucket index page. This index.html then uses one of js file inside the folder within same bucket. With all permissions in place, API Gateway URL loads index.html page but gets 403 forbidden error when calling js file.

Here is the index file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" to="dlg.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="My Application Portal" />
    <title>My Application</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap"
    />
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-b414a784.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Expecting to see index.html to load js file but instead get this error:

[image: 403 Error when calling js file]

[on inspect it shows 403 error]